# How does a live streaming site like twitch work? How would I go about creating one?

Tags: streaming, live-streaming

I want to build a streaming site like twitch, but I have no idea how would I go about setting up one.
I want my clients to be able to live stream through streaming software like OBS, have multiple selectable quality options on my video player. What server and other software would I need?
Thanks in advance!

I have so many questions...
Do I need a CDN?
Can I use WebRtc?
Etc...

I tried searching for this online and stackoverflow but sadly to no avail. The only post I found is 9 years old and outdated.

Answer (score 0):

you can create streaming site through Webrtc.

I give an Example:- YouTube Started streaming video in VP9 Video codec. For live streaming YouTube will depends on Hangouts on Air, which uses WebRTC.

**Webrtc:**

- Mostly Webrtc is using for Real time Collaborations like calls,
  Conferences and Presentations either in P2P or via SFU/MCU/B2B
  servers.
- We can use WebRTC to stream on YouTube or twitch, by converting RTP to RTSP. See [Jitsi POC](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2474026)

Comment: And Yes, You Also Need a CDN. If you try to add a CDN later on a sub-par architecture, you will have to revisit all of your source code and relink it - this is tedious and irritating.